# Error between Azure Web App and Azure Storage in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an app in Azure Web Apps (ASP.NET MVC 4) and want to upload files to Azure Storage. The Web.config is configured with the Storage Emulator:

```
<appSettings>
  ...
  <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  <add key="CloudStorageContainerReference" value="dnc-demo" />
</appSettings>
```

And the connection string is configured in the Web.Release.config  :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StorageConnection" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXX;AccountKey=XXX" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The problem is that when I upload the file(in production) the following error occurs:

```
[SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:10000]
```

How can I fix it??

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, given it's a `SocketException` I'd say your storage isn't the problem. What websocket lib are you using, [socket.io](http://socket.io/)?

Comment: You're applying web.config transformation on your <connectionString> element but defining it in appSettings element.

Comment: @GauravMantri any recommendation in how to fix it??

Comment: May be use `<connectionStrings>` element in both web.config & web.release.config and use `StorageConnection` connection string in your application? Right now it seems you're using `StorageConnectionString` from your `appSettings` in your application.

Comment: @GauravMantri That was the problem, I will pusblish the solution. Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

FIX:

**Web.config** should have the following configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StorageConnection" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And the connection string should be this way in **Web.Release.config**:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StorageConnection"
      connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXX;AccountKey=XXX" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

So the CloudStorageAccount can be initialized this way:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnection"].ToString());
```